# Android align the custom listrow element

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

In my application I use the custom listview for tableview effect.

[image]

But each and every row not align properlly.

only first element give good alignment.

also try the gravity tag.but same effect found.

**my xml code:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:weightSum="5"

    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"

    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/order_id"
        android:id="@+id/tv_orderid"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/name"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:id="@+id/tv_name"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/mobile_number"
        android:id="@+id/tv_mobilenumber"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/order_date_and_time"
        android:id="@+id/tv_orderdate_and_time"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="2"/>

  </LinearLayout>
```

can any one help me to align all the rows properlly.

Comment: In this case you may use a TableLayout. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html

Comment: @oberflansch thanks for info..but I want to know this reason of alignment issue.

Comment: If you dataset is not so large, you can consider to use a `TableLayout` inside a `ScrollView`

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the view with border drawn ? (from developer option of your device)

Comment: Put `android:layout_width="0dp"` instead  of `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` for each `TextView`

Comment: @Joseph82 you save my hours..it works amazing..post as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple use

`android:layout_width="0dp"`

instead of

`android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

for each `TextView`.

The answer is [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight) where is said:

> To create a linear layout in which each child uses the same amount of
>   space on the screen, set the android:layout_height of each view to
>   "0dp" (for a vertical layout) or the android:layout_width of each view
>   to "0dp" (for a horizontal layout). Then set the android:layout_weight
>   of each view to "1".

Comment: your answer works amazing.. but can you give diff bw 0dp & wrap_content for future reference?